# replacing a string using comparator in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting, comparator

I was wondering if it is possible to compare recursively strings within a file using comparator and replace a string based on an element within it. I have some data:

```
331028124,24,7912,CF,1,1
331028124,24,7631,2B,2,1
331028124,24,5909,1B,3,1   
331028124,24,8394,P,3,2       
331028124,24,7245,LF,4,1
331028124,17,9194,SS,1,1
```

I would like to get

```
331028124,24,7912,CF,1,1
331028124,24,7631,2B,2,1
331028124,24,8394,P,3,2       
331028124,24,7245,LF,4,1
331028124,17,9194,SS,1,1
```

Effectively what this should do is compare two strings say `331028124,24,5909,1B,3,1` and `331028124,24,8394,P,3,2`

and then replace the first string with the second string because of a higher number in the last value of the string...

So far I have:

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.DataInputStream;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.Comparator;
    import java.util.List;

    public class BattingOrder {

    String game_ID;
    String team_ID;
    String player_ID;
    String position;
    String battingOrder;
    String subOrder;

    public BattingOrder(String game, String team, String player, String place,
        String batter, String sub) {
        game_ID = game;
        team_ID = team;
        player_ID = player;
        position = place;
        battingOrder = batter;
        subOrder = sub;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
    return game_ID + "," + team_ID + "," + player_ID + "," + position + ","
            + battingOrder;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(
            "BatterInfo.txt");
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            List<BattingOrder> sortList = new ArrayList<BattingOrder>();
                for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null;) {
                    String delims = "[,]";
                    String[] parsedData = line.split(delims);
                    sortList.add(new BattingOrder(parsedData[0], parsedData[1],
                parsedData[2], parsedData[3], parsedData[4], parsedData[5]));
    }
            System.out.println("Before Sort");
    for (BattingOrder order : sortList) {
        System.out.println(order);
    }

    Collections.sort(sortList, new Comparator<BattingOrder>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(BattingOrder one, BattingOrder two) {
            if (one.game_ID.equals(two.game_ID)
                    || one.team_ID.equals(two.team_ID)
                    || one.battingOrder.equals(two.battingOrder)) {
                return one.subOrder.compareTo(two.subOrder);
            } else {
                return one.team_ID.compareTo(two.team_ID);
            }

        }
    });
    System.out.println("After Sort");
    for (BattingOrder order : sortList) {
        System.out.println(order);
    }

    br.close();

}

}
```

Output:

```
Before Sort
  331028124,24,7912,CF,1,1
  331028124,24,7631,2B,2,1
  331028124,24,5909,1B,3,1   
  331028124,24,8394,P,3,2       
  331028124,24,7245,LF,4,1
  331028124,17,9194,SS,1,1    
    After Sort
  331028124,24,7912,CF,1,1
  331028124,24,7631,2B,2,1
  331028124,24,7245,LF,4,1
  331028124,24,5909,1B,3,1   
  331028124,17,9194,SS,1,1    
  331028124,24,8394,P,3,2
```

I want:

```
331028124,24,7912,CF,1,1
331028124,24,7631,2B,2,1
331028124,24,8394,P,3,2       
331028124,24,7245,LF,4,1
331028124,17,9194,SS,1,1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It has sorted your data as you have asked your program to do. I'm not sure what you actually want to do is clear enough to provide an answer.

Comment: Looks to me that you want to Keep a Set of BattingOrder,and every time you encounter a BattingOrder that is better that what is on the set, you do a replacement.

Comment: I see they have to be same team, same game and same battingOrder to be conflicting? And the deciding factor is the subOrder? (am I correct)?

Comment: @BoristheSpider I've updated what I want the output to be...basically replace the 3rd line by the 4th line because the last number (2) is greater that (1) ie...better

Comment: @koala421 OK... I'm doing some code right now... I'll take some more time but It will be worth it... you'll see...

Comment: Okay, 1) store your data in a **proper** `Object` - with numbers stored as numbers. 2) implement your `equals` method as you have described. 3) put data in a `Set` and use the `contains` method.

Comment: @gtgaxiola I'm excited :)

Comment: @BoristheSpider Does that mean I will not be using the Collection.sort or lists in this? Because when I changed what you asked it is giving errors for `sortList.add` and it's looking for strings instead of int/double values

Answer (score 0):

In order to treat `BattingOrder` objects the same on certain fields (but still determine who has better ranking)

You must override the `equals` method as well as the `hashCode` as well as put an `identifier`

```
/** 
 *  Different BattingOrders who share these 3 fields
 *  will get the same identifier
 */
public String identifier() {
    return game_ID +"-" + team_ID + "-" + battingOrder;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof BattingOrder) {
        BattingOrder b = (BattingOrder) obj;
        if (this.game_ID.equals(game_ID) && this.team_ID.equals(b.team_ID) && this.battingOrder.equals(b.battingOrder)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}


@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 5;
    hash = 59 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.game_ID);
    hash = 59 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.team_ID);
    hash = 59 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.battingOrder);
    return hash;
}
```

Also I made `BattingOrder` implement `Comparable`

```
@Override
public int compareTo(BattingOrder o) {
    if (this.identifier().equals(o.identifier())) {
        return this.subOrder.compareTo(o.subOrder);
    } else if (this.game_ID.equals(o.game_ID) && this.team_ID.equals(o.team_ID)) {
        return this.battingOrder.compareTo(o.battingOrder);
    } else {
        return o.team_ID.compareTo(this.team_ID);
    }
}
```

Now in your `main` you set up some `Set` Collection where you keep track of your `BattingOrder` objects

I am using:

```
HashMap<String,BattingOrder> players = new HashMap<>();
```

Where the **Key** is the BattingOrder's `identifier` and the **Value** is the BattingOrder

Now `for-each line you are reading` do the following:

```
 String[] parsedData = s.split(",");
 BattingOrder bo = new BattingOrder(parsedData[0], parsedData[1],parsedData[2], parsedData[3], parsedData[4], parsedData[5]);
 if(players.containsKey(bo.identifier())) {
     BattingOrder inMap = players.get(bo.identifier());
     if(bo.compareTo(inMap) > 0) {
         players.put(bo.identifier(), bo);
     }
 } else {
     players.put(bo.identifier(), bo);
 }
```

Once you have read all the lines:

Convert your `HashMap` into a `List`

```
List<BattingOrder> battingOrderList = new ArrayList<>(players.values());
Collections.sort(battingOrderList);
```

Here is [the code and main tester](http://pastebin.com/abCwqL1g)

Comment: **This Will Not Work**!! `hashCode` is **not unqiue**. You will end up randomly getting the wrong elements in your `Map`. Please read up on how `hashCode()` and `equals()` works.

Comment: @BoristheSpider actually I want higher collision on the hashCode() since I am using it as the key... I want different BattingOrders to collide on specific fields and then determine which one has the higher ranking to be put on the HashMap

Comment: Yes, but `hashCode` overflows. You will have collisions on _other_ fields seemingly at random. When that happens your assumptions that the collision is only on `subOrder` is false and the code fails. The whole point of a hashcode is that the search space is smaller than the search space of all objects.

Comment: @BoristheSpider my equals() and hashCode() perform the checks on the same fields therefore is still honors the [contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29)

Comment: As another note this definition is not _consistent with equals_ and hence breaks the requirement of the `compareTo` method contract.

Comment: Yes, equals and hashcode are implemented correctly. See my comment about compareTo. My problem is that when your hashcode overflows you **will** have a case where `a.hashCode() == b.hashCode()` and **not** `a.equals(b) == true`, which is consistent with the contract for the methods but not with your assumptions in the implementation.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I think I found my logic flaw... it is not the actual override of equals() or hashCode(), but that I am using hashCode() as the key in the Map therefore I can provide false positives..... I'm Changing the Key to be a String identifier which only collides on the specific fields and doesn't overflow

Comment: @gtgaxiola when I try to implement **Comparable** it wants to add a `compare` method...Do I use the Collection.sort that I currently have?

Comment: In my example the compareTo() that I provide is needed to check if a BattingOrder must be taken out of the HashMap.. (not just for the sorting)